# Do ValueEventListeners count as connections to Realtime Database in terms of pricing?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I couldn't understand firebase's realtime database pricing. It says that ["A simultaneous connection is equivalent to one mobile device, browser tab, or server app connected to the database."](https://firebase.google.com/support/faq/#pricing-simultaneous) and that at the cheapest plan i'm limited to 100 connections.

But what counts as a connection to realtime database? Is it the number of devices that initialized the firebase database at the beginning of the app's execution, so if I have 50 simultaneous users I will have 50 connections, or each valueEventListener counts as a connection, i.e: if my app uses 5 valueEventListeners I have 5 connections that count toward the limit?

Comment: A listener is not a connection.  The app will only maintain a single connection at a time which all listeners share.